# Remove command echo in status bar

Tags: normal-mode

I've noticed that sometimes in ViM the status bar shows me the command I've just executed (for instance, if I keep the key 'l' pressed to keep going right, I see at the bottom right of the screen a blinking 'l'). This is useful if I'm typing a composite command such as `d3j`, but it's annoying to see this "immediate" commands blinking at the bottom of the screen. Is there a way to disable this behavior only for the latter (i.e. "immediate") commands?

Thanks a lot.

EDIT: I noticed it happens only with python files (.py). I do not know if this helps...

Comment: `showcmd` determines whether or not the command is displayed; if it "lags," it may be because the terminal cannot draw fast enough relative to the amount of times the key is repeated. (PS holding `l` is a bit of anti-pattern)

Comment: @D.BenKnoble You're right, it also "lags", but this only happens with python scripts (files with .py extensions) and not with other filetypes. Moreover, `:set noshowcmd` makes ViM not show intermediate commands - i.e. which are part of a composite command - (if I type `d`, ViM waits for another character, but I cannot see the `d` at the bottom of the screen, but this partially solves the problem, as I cannot see the `l` being echoed there).